# Programmatically replace GridView cell contents on load

Tags: wpf, gridview, textblock, gridviewcolumn

I am working on a program in WPF for the first time. I have a ListView in GridView mode displaying data from a bound dataset (which is grabbed from a database).

In my database, "date of birth" is not a required field. As such, any record without a dob had the value set to `DateTime.MinValue`. On each of these minimum value dates, the date shows in the cell as 01/01/0001. I am trying to find a way to either format the cell so that `DateTime.MinValue` doesn't show, or replace each `MinValue` with `""`.

My thought was to either use the "Loaded" event of the textblock the date is in and replace each instance of "01/01/0001", or loop through the dataset before sending it to the GridView and remove/replace them there. I've not had any luck figuring out how to do either.

My xaml code for the GridView is:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="resultsListView" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" Margin="0,54,0,28" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Table}">
    <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"
            Header="Last Name" 
            Width="150"/>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" 
            Header="First Name"
            Width="100"/>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MiddleName}" 
            Header="Middle Name"
            Width="100"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Date of Birth" Width="100">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" Text="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth, StringFormat='{}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'}" Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code for the DataSet:

```
private void FillListView(DataSet ds)
{
    if (resultsListView.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        resultsListView.Items.Clear();
    }
    resultsListView.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Any advice on how to show blanks for `DateTime.MinValue` in my GridView would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make an `IValueConverter` that deals with this, and include it in your binding expression.

In your resources:

```
<local:DateTimeConverter x:Key="DateTimeConverter" />
```

Then update your binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth, 
                          Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter},
                          ConverterParameter='MM/dd/yyyy'}" />
```

Then define the class:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
```

This has two methods.  You need only to implement `Convert` (unless you're planning on using two-way binding).  In this method, you can take the format string via a paramater (as I've passed in the binding expression above) and also check for `DateTime.MinValue` and return a blank string.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I used the Convert/Convert Back code from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx - the only thing that hung me up was figuring out how to declare my namespace in the xaml. 

For anyone else, you need to use xmlns:local="clr-namespace:-your namespace-"

Comment: You're welcome.  Value converters are really useful for this kind of thing.  You can define public properties on your converter class and then add different resources with different configurations.  For example, you might have a boolean that controls whether DateTime.MinValue is blanked out, then you can reuse the same class in different ways.